# Why does my sort function not work properly?(Python)

Tags: python

My code all works and the List works but for some reason when I try to sort it , the list doesn't sort to ascending order but instead a random order.So while the list changes it doesn't to descending order. When I tried the x.sort(reverse=True) an error message popped up saying it couldn't be in integer form.
Can anyone help me?

```
score=input('What is your score?')
Scorefile=open('score.txt','a')
Scorefile.write(score)
Scorefile.write("\n")
Scorefile.close()
Scorefile = open('score.txt','r')
with open('score.txt','r') as Scorefile:
     scores=Scorefile.readline()
     List=[]
     while scores:
           scores2=(scores.strip())
           int(scores2)
           List.append(scores2)
           scores=Scorefile.readline()
List.sort()
print(List)
#Output(not in ascending order)
['12', '12', '12', '12', '12', '13', '15', '17', '4', '5', '6']
```

Comment: it's sorted lexographically, if you want it sorted as integers you need to specify that or convert to integers

Answer (score 3):

Your elements are strings (type `str`), not integers (type `int`). Your code currently seems to be sorting by lexographical order.

Try converting your elements to `int`s before sorting. Change these lines in your code:

```
int(scores2)
List.append(scores2)
```

to this:

```
List.append(int(scores2))
```

The statement `int(scores2)` on a line on its own does not do anything useful, you have to use the output of `int()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not sorting numbers, it's sorting strings. As strings of characters, they are sorted.

You can solve this by changing this line

```py
        int(scores2)
```

to this.

```py
        scores2 = int(scores2)
```

Right now you are converting the value to an integer, but not actually using that integer anywhere. I think that is where the confusion is coming from.